# BigQuery issues uploading table from Bucket

Tags: json, upload, google-bigquery, import-from-csv

I keep trying uploading a table into BigQuery from Google Cloud Platform.
I get a hard to believe amount of errors every time, no matter how many I allow

Last fail load reported this, for example:

> "Error while reading data, error message: CSV table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 11034; errors: 10001. Please look into the errors[] collection for more details."

I tried with and without imposing a variables JSON schema, including the write preference (write if empty), Ignore unknown values, allowing quoted newlines, and allowing jagged rows.

I have no idea how to look into the errors[] collection to get more details.

I manage to upload something when allowing for 10m errors, but I believe I am losing entries I would otherwise save. Am I wrong?

Comment: If this is a CSV file it's wrongly formatted. It should go without errors if it's properly formatted and escaped.

Comment: +1 for above comment. After hours of head banging, its usually a realization that something is messed up with the way csv is formatted. Make sure delimiters are set properly, download the sample of file and check if all columns are intact, etc.

Comment: The error was located in the coding of dates variables (coded as NUMERIC). 
Some reported some invalid characters (i.e. "/").

Error was accessed through the BigQuery Cloud Shell (a command line), using the following code:

bq --format=prettyjson show -j <jobname>

Comment: So which format are exactly your dates? Did you specified the schema or is it autodetect? If so, what type is BigQuery detecting?